# Azure policy - deny resource creation with specific tag

Tags: azure, tags, policy

there is a way to deny any kind of resource creation without a specific tag.
For example, i cant create a storage account without tag "environment", but i don't want specify into the policy the value of the tag "environment".
And i don't wont that the resource storage will be create with the tag "environment" empty.

There a ways to deny all'resource without:
"environment":"*"

The expected result is a deny message if the tag environment are empty or missing

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a policy as below

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags['environment']",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['environment']",
          "equals": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle tagging IMO is to enforce a certain set of tags on resource group creation, and then pair that with "Inherit Tags and Values from Resource Group" on resources. This way at the time of creation of the resource group you can deny the creation unless a defined value is set for "environment", and then any resource created inside that resource group will inherit that tag and value.

If you look at the Policy Definitions in Azure Policy and search for "tag" you will see several options for enforcing and auditing resource tagging.